# How can I archive multiple articles on Instapaper at once?

Tags: automation, instapaper

Instapaper is useful for automatically sending articles to my Kindle. However, once they're sent they still remain in my reading list, unarchived. I'm looking for a way to automatically archive them, or to mass archive all articles older than a certain date at once.

Answer (score 2):

I settled on a quick JS solution:

```
$("a.js_archive_single.action_link>span.ipicon.ipicon-archive").each(
    function(){
        $(this).click()
    }
)
```

This automatically clicks on all archive buttons on the page.

**Warning:** this will archive articles on all older pages as well (since Instapaper automatically loads more articles when you archive some).